# Does ReentrantLock use Decorator Design Pattern in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, reentrantlock

ReentrantLock contains an abstract class `Sync`, and `Sync` has two subclasses `FairSync` and `NonFairSync`. I want to know is this `Decorator Design Pattern`?

BTW, is there any good resources about **Design Pattern usage in java source code**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries

Comment: @jaco0646, Wow, thus a good resource, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not. `Sync` (and `FairSync`/`NonFairSync` as well) are only inner classes that are used as an attribute of `ReentrantLock` (basically, this is only composition, no special pattern involved here).

The second question will result in opinion-based answers since each person has its own tastes and colors about design patterns (so there is no single *good* resource about design patterns).

If you really want to start somewhere, start on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) where each pattern is explained quite neutrally but in any case it will let you know when (and if) it is appropriate to use them.